# Triggering copy event with no selection on Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, safari, mobile-safari

Adding an `oncopy` handler to an input field to get some custom behaviour with no text selected works in Safari on macOS (and other browsers), but on Safari on iPad, nothing happens when pressing **⌘+C**.

Is it possible to trigger this on Safari on iPad?

Here's a simple example that doesn't work on Mobile Safari:

```html
 <input type="textbox" oncopy="alert('copy!')">
```

Comment: This works as expected on iOS (iphone) using native touch controls. Admittedly, iOS and iPadOS safari are not the same. However, have you tried to test the input event with touch controls? Your description implies you're using a bluetooth keyboard – it might make a difference. Besides, I recommend to set a default value to your snippet like so   
`<input type="textbox" oncopy="alert('copy!')" value="copy me">`

Answer (score 2):

According to [Safari Supported Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html) , `oncopy` is a JavaScript delegate. Therefore, JavaScript solution for this should work on any Safari running device. JavaScript detects keyboard shortcuts in this solution.

Sources: [How TO - Copy Text to Clipboard](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp) , [How to detect copy paste commands](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-detect-copy-paste-commands-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript/) , [Toptal keycodes library](https://www.toptal.com/developers/keycode/table-of-all-keycodes) & [Safari HTML Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html)

```js
// Global variable to get input value (Input element must have an id)
let justCopiedFrom = '';

// Clicked element's value into dynamic variable
function inputToVar(x) {
  justCopiedFrom = x.id;
}

// Detect [⌘/Ctrl + C] & [⌘/Ctrl + V]
document.body.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
    e = e || window.event;

    var key = e.which || e.keyCode; // keyCode detection
    var ctrl = e.ctrlKey ? e.ctrlKey : ((key === 17) ? true : false); // ctrl detection
    var cmd_h = e.metaKey ? e.metaKey : ((key === 91) ? true : false); // ⌘ detection

    if ( key == 86 && ctrl || key == 86 && cmd_h ) {

        // Copy the text inside the text field
        console.log("⌘/Ctrl + V");

    } else if ( key == 67 && ctrl || key == 67 && cmd_h ) {
        let valueOf = document.getElementById(justCopiedFrom);

        // Select the text field
        valueOf.select();
        valueOf.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); // For mobile devices
      
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(valueOf.value);
        console.log(`⌘/Ctrl + C (${valueOf.value})`);
    }

},false);
```

```html
<!-- Input must have an Id so it can be passed with JS function (inputToVar) -->
<p><small>Add some random text here and try copy and paste keyboard shortcuts</small></p>
<input id="text-input" type="textbox" onclick="inputToVar(this);">
```